# Extracting data using Python os.path.pardir: get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, os.path

I'm trying to extract data to my local machine using os.path.pardir and os.path.join to get the directories. However I am getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\sophi\\climate_repos\\notebooks\\src\\data\\get_raw_data.py'
```

I have also tried using the very same path (without double backslash) i.e.:
`data_path = r'C:\\Users\\sophi\\climate_repos\\notebooks\\src\\data\\get_raw_data.py'`
and this works fine, so I'm not sure why it isn't recognizing the joined path as a directory? Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
%%writefile $get_raw_data_script_file

import os
from dotenv import find_dotenv,load_dotenv
from requests import session
import logging

payload = { 
    'action': 'login'
    'username': os.environ.get("KAGGLE_USERNAME"),
    'password': os.environ.get("KAGGLE_PASSWORD")

}

def extract_data(url, file_path):
    '''
    method to extract data
    '''
#setup session
    with session() as c:
        c.post('https://www.kaggle.com/account/login', data =payload)
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as handle:
            response = c.get(url,stream = True)
            for block in response.iter_content(1024):
                handle.write(block)
                
def main(project_dir):
    '''main method
    '''
    #get logger
    logger = logging.getlogger(_name_)
    logger.info('getting raw data')
    
    #url
    url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/berkeleyearth/climate-change-earth-surface-temperature-data/download/GlobalLandTemperaturesByCity.csv'
    
#file path
raw_data_path = os.path.join(project_dir,'data','raw')
data_path = os.path.join(raw_data_path,'GlobalLandTemperaturesByCity.csv')

#extract data
extract_data(url,data_path)
logger.info('downloaded raw data')

if _name_ == '_main_':
    #getting root directory
  #  project_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(_file_),os.pardir,os.pardir)
    project_dir = r'C:\Users\sophi\climate_repos'
    #setup logger
    log_fmt = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(level-logging.INFO, format = log_fmt)
    
    #find .env automaticcal by walking up directories until found
    dotenv_path = find_dotenv()
    #load up the entries as environment variables
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path)
    
    #call the main
    main(project_dir)
```

Comment: According to the code, `GlobalLandTemperaturesByCity.csv` is the file that is written, right?

Comment: Could you please verify that the indentation in the question is the same with the executed program?

Comment: Yes it should all work fine

Comment: Could you post the exact non working version of the code? As it is, `data_path` is assigned a value before `project_dir` is defined.